# SQL - how to replace my sum results in one number

Tags: sql

I have a query that sums some columns

```
SELECT P, sum (K)
FROM table
GROUP BY P
```

and i want that if the sum is more than 1 i will have 1 in results. Meaning instead of:

```
P K
1 2
3 4
23 0
```

I will have:

```
P K
1 1
3 1
23 0
```

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `SQL Server`? `MySQL`? `Oracle`? `DB2`? etc..

Answer (score 2):

use `CASE`

```
SELECT P, 
       (CASE WHEN sum(K) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Result
FROM   tableName
GROUP  BY P
```

**UPDATE**

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/11c56/1)

Thanks to [Luv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841054/luv)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P, LEAST(1, sum (K))
FROM table
GROUP BY P
```

It sounds like there are 2 conditions sum(K) > 1 then you want want, the only option for sum(K) < 1 is 0. So this will give you that.